# I can create the heap, but the first element of the array is untouched

Tags: java, sorting, heap, heapsort

HeapSort.java:

```
public class HeapSort{
    public static void run(int[] array, int size){
        heapify(array, size, 1);
    }
    
    private static void heapify(int[] array, int size, int v){
        if (v*2>=size){
            return;
        }
        
        heapify(array, size, v*2);
        heapify(array, size, v*2+1);
        fixHeap(array, size, v);
    }
    
    private static void fixHeap(int[] array, int size, int v){
        if (v*2>=size){
            return;
        }
        
        int u = 0;
        if (array[v*2]>array[(v*2)+1]){
            u = v*2;
        } else{
            u = (v*2)+1;
        }
        
        if (array[u]>array[v]){
            int temp = array[u];
            array[u] = array[v];
            array[v] = temp;
            fixHeap(array, size, u);
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Main m = new Main();
        m.run();
    }
    
    private void run(){
        int size = 8;
        int[] array = new int[size];
        
        this.randomArray(array,size);
        System.out.println("");
        
        HeapSort.run(array,size);
        
        this.printArray(array, size);
        System.out.println("");
    }
    
    private void randomArray(int[] array, int size){
        Random r = new Random();
        int el = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<size; ++i){
            el = r.nextInt(50);
            array[i] = el;
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    
    private void printArray(int[] array, int size){
        for(int i=0; i<size; ++i){
                System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }   
}
```

Output like these:

```
44 18 40 40 11 4 14 6 
44 40 40 18 11 4 14 6
```

or:

```
30 43 21 41 25 16 36 20 
30 43 25 41 21 16 36 20
```

or:

```
42 38 19 20 32 35 17 21 
42 38 35 21 32 19 17 20
```

as you can see, the heap is created, but the first element is untouched. How can I fix this problem?

I thought that I could do a scan in all the array and find the maximum and put it in the radix (first position), but is there a more elegant way to fix this?

Comment: There are two ways: either allocate an array one size larger than needed and leave the first element blank, or correct all the index formulae to work with 0-based indexing instead of 1-based indexing.

Comment: @kaya3 the problem is that I really don't know how to correct all the index formulae to work with 0... I thought that I could find the maximum of the array and put it in the first element of the array, but I think this will decrease the performance